# Using PIL, how do i save an image from manipulated after using .load()?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How do I save an image file from data manipulated using image.load()?

This is my code used to merge two pictures of the same size

```
from PIL import Image
import random

image1 = Image.open("me.jpg")
image2 = Image.open("otherme.jpg")

im1 = image1.load()
im2 = image2.load()

width, height = image1.size

newimage = Image.new("RGB",image1.size)
newim = newimage.load()

xx = 0
yy = 0

while xx < width:
    while yy < height:
        if random.randint(0,1) == 1:
            newim[xx,yy] = im1[xx,yy]
        else:
            newim[xx,yy] = im2[xx,yy]
        yy = yy+1
    xx = xx+1

newimage.putdata(newim)
newimage.save("new.jpg")
```

When I run it I get this error though.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/dave/Desktop/face/squares.py", line 27, in <module>
newimage.putdata(newim)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1215, in putdata
self.im.putdata(data, scale, offset)
TypeError: argument must be a sequence
```

Isn't the dictionary from using .load() a sequence? I can't find anyone else on google having this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dictionary` (which isn't really a dictionary) returned by `load` *is* the data in the image. You don't have to reload it with `putdata`. Just remove that line.

Also, use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop:

```
for xx in range(0, width):
    for yy in range(0, height):
        if random.randint(0,1) == 1:
            newim[xx,yy] = im1[xx,yy]
        else:
            newim[xx,yy] = im2[xx,yy]
```

Now there's no need to initialize and increment `xx` and `yy`.

You could even use `itertools.product`:

```
for xx, yy in itertools.product(range(0, width), range(0, height)):
    if random.randint(0,1) == 1:
        newim[xx,yy] = im1[xx,yy]
    else:
        newim[xx,yy] = im2[xx,yy]
```